# How to convert signed 32-bit int to unsigned 32-bit int?

Tags: python, integer, unsigned, signed, type-conversion

This is what I have, currently. Is there any nicer way to do this?

```
import struct
def int32_to_uint32(i):
    return struct.unpack_from("I", struct.pack("i", i))[0]
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not sure if it's "nicer" or not...

```
import ctypes

def int32_to_uint32(i):
    return ctypes.c_uint32(i).value
```

Comment: That returns a Python integer type, though, which probably isn't a meaningful result in this context, as it isn't actually a uint32 anymore. I suppose it depends on how he's using it.

Comment: @Cairnarvon: For `1` and `-1`, the OP's version returns an `int` and a `long` respectively. My version returns a `long` for both.

Comment: Nice! I'd probably prefer this. Is this as cross-platform as `struct`?

Comment: @Claudiu: As for cross-platformness, all I can say is I think so.

Comment: @Claudiu: FWIW, in Python 3.3 both your and my version return `int` for both cases. Also, what's the basis of your preference? You've never said what sort of _nicer_ you're after.

Comment: By "nicer" I meant "more pythonic". I'm not sure what that would be in this case. But it seemed hackish to pack it into a one-member struct and then to read it back out. This does essentially the same but it's a bit clearer, and doesn't require an array index.

Comment: @Claudiu: I see. If you change my answer to `return int(ctypes.c_uint32(i).value)` it will return `int` and `long` for the two cases like your `struct` version does -- which is better in that it makes more sense in my opinion.

Comment: Accepting this. I like it as it makes it more obvious what the code does.

Answer (score 7):

using numpy for example:

```
import numpy
result = numpy.uint32( numpy.int32(myval) )
```

or even on arrays,

```
arr = numpy.array(range(10))
result = numpy.uint32( numpy.int32(arr) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I just started learning python, but something simple like this works for values
in the range of a signed 32-bit integer

```
def uint(x):
  if x < 0:
    return hex(0xffff_ffff - abs(x) + 1)
  else:
    return hex(x)
```

Comment: why would you EVER need an unsigned int in the range of a signed int?

Comment: There are a lot of scenarios where you want to cast signed to unsigned.   Sometimes its necessary when working directly registers on hardware device.  If I remember correctly what I was doing at the time is that I wanted the hex representation for display purposes.  If you, said print(x) you got -1, but I wanted to show the twos-complement hex value of 0xFFFF_FFFF.