# Making sense of uint values

Tags: python, gps

I'm working on extracting gps values from a multiwii board via a python script based on [this repo](https://github.com/alduxvm/pyMultiWii).

I have added this to the init function:

```
self.rawgps = {'fix':0,'numSat':0,'lat':0,'lon':0,'alt':0,'speed':0,'elapsed':0,'timestamp':0}
```

to the getData function:

```
elif cmd == MultiWii.RAW_GPS:
    self.rawgps['fix']=float(temp[0]/10.0)
    self.rawgps['numSat']=float(temp[1]/10.0)
    self.rawgps['lat']=float(temp[2]/10.0)
    self.rawgps['lon']=float(temp[3])
    self.rawgps['alt']=float(temp[4])
    self.rawgps['speed']=float(temp[5])
    self.rawgps['elapsed']=round(elapsed,3)
    self.rawgps['timestamp']="%0.2f" % (time.time(),) 
    return self.rawgps
```

and to the getDataInf function

```
elif cmd == MultiWii.RAW_GPS:
    self.rawgps['fix']=float(temp[0])
    self.rawgps['numSat']=float(temp[1])
    self.rawgps['lat']=float(temp[2])
    self.rawgps['lon']=float(temp[3])
    self.rawgps['alt']=float(temp[4])
    self.rawgps['speed']=float(temp[5])
    self.rawgps['elapsed']="%0.3f" % (elapsed,)
    self.rawgps['timestamp']="%0.2f" % (time.time(),)
```

I'm basing this on the output I'm reading at: http://www.multiwii.com/wiki/index.php?title=Multiwii_Serial_Protocol

When I call the code with

```
board.getData(MultiWii.RAW_GPS)
print board.rawgps
```

The output looks really off. This is what I'm getting

```
{'alt': -12738.0, 'timestamp': '1494887366.41', 'lat': 6434.0, 'speed': 208.0, 'fix': 2561.0, 'lon': 24919.0, 'numSat': -21303.0, 'elapsed': 0.009}
{'alt': -12738.0, 'timestamp': '1494887366.41', 'lat': 6434.0, 'speed': 208.0, 'fix': 2561.0, 'lon': 24919.0, 'numSat': -21303.0, 'elapsed': 0.009}
{'alt': -12738.0, 'timestamp': '1494887366.41', 'lat': 6434.0, 'speed': 208.0, 'fix': 2561.0, 'lon': 24919.0, 'numSat': -21303.0, 'elapsed': 0.009}
{'alt': -12738.0, 'timestamp': '1494887366.41', 'lat': 6434.0, 'speed': 208.0, 'fix': 2561.0, 'lon': 24919.0, 'numSat': -21303.0, 'elapsed': 0.009}
{'alt': -12738.0, 'timestamp': '1494887366.41', 'lat': 6434.0, 'speed': 208.0, 'fix': 2561.0, 'lon': 24919.0, 'numSat': -21303.0, 'elapsed': 0.009}
```

The lat and lon don't look like typical lat/lon values to me. Maybe it's a different data type? The fixed, I'm expecting a 1 or 0. And numSats, while I don't see a definition, I feel like it should be the number of satellites I'm connected to, which likely won't be over 15... or negative.

Altitude also shouldn't be negative, and this was all taken while stationary, so the speed should be zero. Python isn't my normal language so maybe I'm losing some in the syntax.

Comment: In order to help, we need to see the raw input data that's in `temp`.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, you could use `ctypes.c_uint32()` in a manner similar to what's in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16452899/355230).